# How does Flink treat checkpoints and state within IterativeStream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I can see in the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html#state-checkpoints-in-iterative-jobs) that:

> Flink currently only provides processing guarantees for jobs without
>   iterations. Enabling checkpointing on an iterative job causes an
>   exception. In order to force checkpointing on an iterative program the
>   user needs to set a special flag when enabling checkpointing:
>   env.enableCheckpointing(interval, force = true).
>
> Please note that records in flight in the loop edges (and the state
>   changes associated with them) will be lost during failure.

Does this refer to iterations within batch jobs or to iterative streams, or both?

If it refers to iterative streams, what state of the following operators would be available in the event of failure?  (Example taken [from this conversation](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Regarding-Broadcast-of-datasets-in-streaming-context-tp6456p6552.html) about sharing state across operators using a `ConnectedIterativeStreams` and terminating the iteration with `.closeWith(stream.broadcast())`).

```
DataStream<Point> input = ...
ConnectedIterativeStreams<Point, Centroids> inputsAndCentroids = input.iterate().withFeedbackType(Centroids.class)
DataStream<Centroids> updatedCentroids = inputsAndCentroids.flatMap(new MyCoFlatmap())
inputsAndCentroids.closeWith(updatedCentroids.broadcast())

class MyCoFlatmap implements CoFlatMapFunction<Point, Centroid, Centroid>{...}
```

Would there be any change if `MyCoFlatmap` were to be a `CoProcessFunction` instead of a `CoFlatMapFunction` (meaning it could hold state too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation only applies to Flink's `DataStream`/Streaming API when using iterations. When using the `DataSet`/Batch API, there are no limitations.

When using streaming iterations you actually don't lose operator state but you might lose records which have been sent from an operator back to the iteration head via the loop edge. In your example, records sent from the `updatedCentroids` to the `inputsAndCentroids` might be lost in case of a failure. Hence, Flink cannot guarantee exactly once processing guarantees in this case.

There is actually a [Flink improvement proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-16%3A+Loop+Fault+Tolerance) which addresses this shortcoming. However, it has not been finished yet.

Comment: Thanks, Till - the issue tracking FLIP-16 (FLINK-3257) appears to have stalled. Do you know if it's being actively worked on?

Comment: Afaik, there is nobody in the community actively working on this feature. However, I know that some community members want to develop ML applications on top of Flink (using the streaming API) where iteration support is a strict requirement. Consequently, I would expect that the community adds this feature soon.

Comment: Yes, on GH (https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/1668) it looks like there was active development by SenorCarbone until Mar '17, then it all went quiet.